# Getting LIST from the request attribute

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc

Im trying to set a list as an hidden variable in JSP and trying to access the same in controller.
This is my JSP,

```
<form:form id="TacReviewForm" commandName="taxReviewRequest" modelAttribute="taxReviewRequest" >
<form:hidden path="taxErrorDto" />
....................

---->
```

Where taxReviewRequest is the model and taxErrorDto is a list inside taxReviewRequest.
Now, I am trying to access the same in the controller class like below,

```
List<TaxErrorDto> taxErrorDto =  (List<TaxErrorDto>)request.getAttribute("taxErrorDto");

System.out.println("!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!"+taxErrorDto);
```

Now when i try to print the same in the class it returns null.
Can someone help me with this please?

Tried --------------
URL in JS is: "${pageContext.request.contextPath}/otp/updateReviewDetail.html?taxReviewRequest=${taxReviewRequest}"

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/updateReviewDetail.html")
    public ModelAndView launchReviewDetail(HttpServletRequest request, @RequestParam("taxReviewRequest") TaxReviewReqDto taxReviewRequest) {
List<TaxErrorDto> taxErrorDto = TaxReviewRequest.getTaxErrorDto();
...
}
```

Getting this error

```
[7/7/14 11:15:24:435 EDT] 00000084 webapp        E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp logServletError SRVE0293E: [Servlet Error]-[meirpt]: com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppErrorReport: SRVE0295E: Error reported: 500
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppDispatcherContext.sendError(WebAppDispatcherContext.java:637)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.srt.SRTServletResponse.sendError(SRTServletResponse.java:1187)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.srt.SRTServletResponse.sendError(SRTServletResponse.java:1169)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponseWrapper.sendError(HttpServletResponseWrapper.java:141)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponseWrapper.sendError(HttpServletResponseWrapper.java:141)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponseWrapper.sendError(HttpServletResponseWrapper.java:141)
```

---

Comment: I do not understand : in an form input parameter, be it text, textarea or hidden what you pass on ouput (controller -> browser) and what you get on input (browser -> controller) is a mere string. Have you configured a converter `List<TaxErrorDto>` <-> `String` ? And in your controller method, I think you need `@ModelAttribute("taxReviewRequest")` instead of `@RequestParam("taxReviewRequest")`

Comment: @Serge Ballesta..Tried as modelAttribute but it did not work.

Comment: And what about `List<TaxErrorDto>` <-> `String` conversion ?

Answer (score 0):

In Spring we do that like this...I think it will help you.Thanks

```
public ModelAndView registerProcess(@ModelAttribute("taxReviewRequest") TaxReviewRequest taxReviewRequest)
{
   List<TaxErrorDto> taxErrorDto =  taxReviewRequest.getTaxErrorDto();
}
```

Comment: @user3812843.. tried as you mentioned. See my edit above. Im getting a different error.

Comment: @RequestMapping(value = "/updateReviewDetail.html")
    public ModelAndView launchReviewDetail(HttpServletRequest request, @RequestParam("taxReviewRequest") TaxReviewReqDto taxReviewRequest) {
List<TaxErrorDto> taxErrorDto = taxReviewRequest.getTaxErrorDto();
...
}

Comment: I think its the same what I have edited. AM i missing something @user3812843

Comment: I unknown with struts but i do this kind of task in spring like this.

Comment: @user3812843.. Yes this is also spring framework. I am sure your code is going to work out. There is some small issue in mine which im unable to get.

Comment: use taxReviewRequest.getTaxErrorDto(); instead of TaxReviewRequest.getTaxErrorDto();